# Is it common to say something is some color?

Tags: word-usage

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/red)

> The dress was bright **red**.

I totally understand this use.

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/nbnRm_3_QKU?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=539)

> The water was a kind of dark **green colour**.

I don't really understand this use.

Is it common to say something is some color?

Does the following one mean the same thing?

> The water was a kind of dark **green**.

Comment: We can use a colour name with the word 'colour' if we are trying to describe a colour which is not one of the main colours, or is in between one colour and another, or we are making a guess at describing it (the phrase 'a kind of' indicates this). His suit was a grey-brown colour; her eyes were a sort of hazel colour.

Comment: If we wish to describe a _shade_ of colour, we might say e.g. 'a blue-green colour'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly common, and afaik is correct usage. It isn't necessary to designate green as a color, but there's nothing wrong with it.